# XSLT 1.0: [not(./@id = preceding::a/@id)] filter shows first element twice

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I seem to be making some kind of simple/stupid mistake.

Given the following (simplified) xml:

```
<xml>
  <a id="0" />
  <a id="0" />
  <a id="0" />
  <a id="2" />
  <a id="2" />
</xml>
```

And given the following (simplified) xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:for-each select="//a[not(./@id = preceding::a/@id)]">
    id=<xsl:value-of select="@id" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives me the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
id=0
id=0
id=2
```

As one can see, the element with `id=0` is processed twice, although it should be processed only once. In the XML input it appears three times, and the problem occurs only for the first element (as the element with `id=2` is correctly processed only once).

Please note that I need to use preceding as filter (not preceding-sibling) because the original XML is more complex. I also need to use XSLT 1.0, because I use Xalan 2.7.1 as Xslt processor.

Comment: I tried with `xsltproc` and got `id=0` only once in the output.

Comment: I tested the snippet you posted and they seem to work fine.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the input! Seems to be a problem of JAXPSAXProcessor! Indeed I fail to use Xalan 2.7.1 as I posted!

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but using the preceding-sibling axis rather than the preceding axis here would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the hint. I know, but what you see is just the SSCCE, and as stated in the answer the original XML is much more complex -- so preceding-sibling does not work in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments I was able to verify that this is a problem of the XSLT processor. On a Mac with `jdk1.7.0_67` when the system property `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null` and thus the platform default is used (see [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html)), this results in the above wrong output.

In other words the real problem is that I failed to set Xalan as the Xslt processor as I posted in the question. Thanks for the help!